# Cannot access private member declared in class 'CObject'

Tags: c++, visual-c++, mfc

I am trying to create a copy constructor for a CStringArray. once the code is compiled, visual studio gave me this error : Cannot access private member declared in class 'CObject'

in example.h I have declared the variable:

```
list<CStringArray>EqptListPpiedsOptions;
```

in example.cpp

I use this as my copy constructor :

```
example::example(const example &data) {
  list<CStringArray>::const_iterator itr = data.EqptListPpiedsOptions.begin();

  while (itr != data.EqptListPpiedsOptions.end()) {
    this->EqptListPpiedsOptions.push_back(*itr);
    itr++;
  }
}
```

How can I correctly use the copy constructor CStringArray List ?

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: @Justin `CStringArray` is part of Microsoft's MFC.

Comment: I think people giving feedback on the question have knowleddge of C++, but not of MFC. `CStringArray` is an **inherent** type of MFC, not a user defined one. The class is derived from `CObject`, so the problem is not the only the copy constructor but also the assignment operator, because . I already explored the same problem on `CArray` as described in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32100432/how-can-i-initialize-the-default-value-of-a-carraycclass-function-parameter-w

Comment: If you can, I recommend you to use a `std::vector<CString>` based on my own evidence: http://stackoverflow.com/a/31755729/383779

Comment: @Mark Ransom. I just use a const_iterator to read the data in the list. I am not using it to modify the data. Is it OK ?

Comment: Sorry, I was rushed and reading the code on my phone. Nothing wrong with, carry on. It would help to have more details on the error, which member is it complaining about and which line generates the error?

Comment: @sergiol interesting observation. You should copy the relevant information to an answer on this question, I think it explains things perfectly.

Comment: @sergiol. I will try this and I will let you know if it works or not. Thank for help and your time. And probably, I can give more details.

Comment: It seems something unintentionally is not present in my comment. After "because" it misses "they are both **private**"

Comment: BTW is list a std:list?