# legacy MFC code (2005) doesn't compile on VC 2010

Tags: c++, visual-studio, mfc, compiler-errors

I have a problem with `CException`.
Probably something has changed in `afx.h`

The error I get is in the following line:

```
throw new CException();
```

The error is

> error C2259: 'CException' : cannot instantiate abstract class due to
>   following members: 'CException::~CException(void)' : is abstract

I never used MFC before and I just need it to compile as fast as I can, does anyone knows what the problem is ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use one of the derived classes.
See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t078xe4f.aspx for detailed info.

Or, instead, use `std::exception`.

Comment: CSimpleException is also abstract !

Comment: I'd avoid `std::exception` in a MFC app, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/143006/why-does-my-mfc-app-hang-when-i-throw-an-exception